# Java EE 6 cluster collections

Tags: jakarta-ee, caching, collections, cluster-computing

I am currently working on a Java EE Application (JSF, CDI, EJB, JPA), which should work in a cluster environment.

I have few Maps and Lists (Collection API ) which serves as caches and are not ready for distribution yet.

I've read in an article that there is a framework which wraps the collection API but I can not find the product via Google.

Any ideas which product could fit for this purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I´ve found the product after a lot of google

[hazelcast](http://www.hazelcast.com/)

This [Tweet](https://twitter.com/harkje/status/299507849359417344) puts me into the right direction

Answer (score 0):

IMHO you're going the wrong way. Collection classes are not synchronized if you are not doing it yourself using Collections.synchronizedXXX() but even this won't do the job if you want to share cache accross cluster.
 If you go this way I would have a look to ConcurrentHashMap. Anyway maintaining cache in Collection classes is rarely a good idea, you have some good framework like ehcache or jbosscache for doing the job for you.
If objects you'are caching are entities, you should better delegate the cache management to the ORM. If you want cache to be shared accross cluster (rarely a good idea too, using database is normaly the right way in this case) you have some vendor specific solution like HASingleton on JBOSS.

Hope i could help you

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few caching frameworks available which support clustering.
Heres my pick

- [Ehcache](http://ehcache.org/) from Terracota
- [OSCache](http://java-source.net/open-source/cache-solutions/oscache)
- [Java Caching System](http://java-source.net/open-source/cache-solutions/jcache)

Well in all my projects i use EHCACHE , its stable , has good documentation and widely used.
This can come in handy when you get stuck with caching set up issue or something , it has high chance that someone would have faced similar issue.

There is whole lot more available in below link
 [Open Caching frameworks in Java](http://java-source.net/open-source/cache-solutions)